# Expansion of gamma function

Tags: taylor-expansion, gamma-function

The lecturer wrote down $\Gamma(x-2)=-\frac{1}{2x}+\cdots$ , but I can't figure out where this comes from? It needs to be in this form so that I can cancel the $x$ with the expansion of another function in order to evaluate at $x=0$.

This is my first time using this site so apologies for any mistakes!

Comment: I suppose a typo since Taylor expansion (built at $x=0$) should give $$\Gamma(x-2)=\frac{1}{2 x}+\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24} \left(21-18
   \gamma +6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$

Comment: How do you find the expansion though?